# Javascript: getFullYear() returning negative values in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have a date string 'Mar 15/18' which I need to parse in order to get dd, mm and yyyy components separately.

When I parse this date string using the below code in Internet Explorer, **-18** is returned:

> var d='Mar 15/18';
>
> var dt=new Date(d);
>
> alert(dt.getFullYear());

This works fine in chrome and returns **2018**. I am unable to think of any reason as to why it would return a negative value in IE.

Comment: `'Mar 15/18'` evaluates as invalid date

Comment: I have tried this on chrome and IE and in both the cases it has returned some value. On chrome this date object is correctly parsed whereas in the case of IE I am getting dd and mm values correctly whereas the issue is coming only for the year part so I am not sure this evaluates as invalid date.

Comment: There are generally 3 types of JavaScript date input formats: ISO Date "2015-03-25" (The International Standard), Short Date "03/25/2015", Long Date "Mar 25 2015" or "25 Mar 2015". So all the 3 above are considered as valid Date string.

Answer (score 0):

Because Javascript getFullYear() is expecting a valid dateObj as its parameter and will return a four-digit year value.

'Mar 15/18' is not a standard dateObj of Javascript. Instead, you should update your value to a valid dateObj if you want to get the correct conversion in IE (Chrome is much smarter than IE).

More details can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Another handy way to deal with date and time object is to use moment.js library.

Comment: thanks @MattYao for your answer but the thing is I don't know what will be the format of incoming date string, I am depending upon the javascript Date class for this and for whatever cases it fails on ,I am doing a regex match of most occurring patterns. I just don't understand why isn't it returning NaN, why does it provide a timestamp when used with Date.parse(). Shouldn't it explicitly say that the date is invalid.